# SQL conditional join challenge

Tags: mysql, sql, join, conditional-statements

I have 2 tables stores and shares in a mysql database. I am trying to avoid an IN clause. Please see below for more details

```
select id, user_id from stores where user_id =7;
+----+---------+
| id | user_id |
+----+---------+
| 36 |       7 |
| 37 |       7 |


select stores_id,share_id from shares where share_id=7;
+-----------+----------+
| stores_id | share_id |
+-----------+----------+
|        15 |        7 |
|        38 |        7 |
```

Now I run this

```
SELECT stores.id
FROM   stores
WHERE  user_id = 7
UNION
(SELECT stores.id
 FROM   stores
 WHERE  id IN (SELECT stores_id
               FROM   shares
               WHERE  share_id = 7));
```

To get the below result:

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
| 36 |
| 37 |
| 15 |
| 38 |
+----+
```

**QUESTION**
How can I rewrite the query so that I don't use the   **IN**  key word.?

Comment: Yes...when I don't know about it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can help to you:

```
select stores.id from stores where user_id = 7  
UNION  
select s1.id from stores s1 
       inner join shares s2 
       on s2.share_id = 7 
       and s1.id = s2.stores_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `EXISTS`:

```
WHERE EXISTS
       ( SELECT 1
           FROM shares
          WHERE share_id = 7
            AND stores_id = stores.id
       )
```

or `JOIN`:

```
JOIN shares
  ON shares.stores_id = stores.id
 AND shares.share_id = 7
```

(Note that the `JOIN` potentially returns multiple copies of some stores, but because `UNION` implies `SELECT DISTINCT`, that won't actually affect your final result-set.)

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is the ID, this will do just fine...

```
SELECT stores.id
FROM   stores
WHERE  user_id = 7

UNION

SELECT stores_id as id
FROM   shares
WHERE  share_id = 7
```

But if you need some data from the other columns in the stores table, INNER JOIN or EXISTS will be your best bet.

Comment: bups. perhaps some store_id is not in stores table ... !

Comment: True, but it's most likely a foreign key, without it, the referential integrity would be lost and the records orphaned. If that's the case, the table should be cleaned and a check-constraint added.

Comment: The idea is to get all the columns in the stores table. Chris - your solution will work if I needed only the store id. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A left join should accomplish what you are looking for:

```
select distinct stores.id 
from stores 
left join shares on stores.id = shares.stores_id
where stores.user_id = 7 
or shares.share_id = 7
```